# Margin-top in css for menu icon not working for particular px

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I try to make icon go up using **margin top : -35px;** under #menu, when I click on it the icon side navigation doesn't work ,but when i give upto -15px the side navigation bar gets displayed. I am not able to figure out the mistake!

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
#menu{
  float: right;
  margin-top: -15px;
  
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity:0.5;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 90px;

}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #808080;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"><i class="material-icons material-spec-icon" title="Show navigation">menu</i></span>
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Process</a>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Without the complete code it's hard to help, but I guess your menu has a higher `z-index` value than your menu icon... Try to add `z-index: 100` to the icon.

Comment: Do you want the menu icon to appear on the same line at the other buttons? Is there a problem with the js?

Comment: @robertpulson yeah but when i align it with other li items , the side navigation doesnt work

Comment: The problem is possibly the negative margin top youre using is making it unclickable. Its a bit hacky, best to use a different solution. Is it possible to make a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the display from block to inline on your a tags:

```
.sidenav a {
  display: inline;
}
```

Then you can remove the margin top.